# Python Reading a file and printing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi I am reading a file data.txt which is in the below format.

```
    Last table change time   : 6:55:12 ago
    Number of table inserts  : 3
    Number of table deletes  : 0
    Number of table drops    : 0
    Number of table age-outs : 0

    Port       Neighbor Device ID             Neighbor Port ID           TTL
    Et1        Arista2                        Ethernet1                  120
    Et2        Arista2                        Ethernet2                  120
    Ma1        Arista2                        Management1                120
```

I need to extract the data and print it as

```
Et1, Arista2, Ethernet1
Et2, Arista2, Ethernet2
Ma1, Arista2, Management1
```

I am using the below code, however I am only able to print

('Et1', 'Et2', 'Ma1')

```
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        for x in xrange(6):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            print zip(*[line.split() for line in f])[0]
        f.close()
```

Comment: Why are you doing that `zip` thing? You don't need a transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract desired content with help of little bit regex.

Try following code snippet:

```
import re

with open('input.txt','r') as fp:
    for x in xrange(7):
        next(fp)

    rx = "\w+"
    for line in fp:
        data = re.findall(u"\w+", line, re.DOTALL)
        if data:
            print(', '.join(data[0:-1]))
```

Depending on file content and format, it will print

```
Et1, Arista2, Ethernet1
Et2, Arista2, Ethernet2
Ma1, Arista2, Management1
```

Comment: works perfect, thanks. In above case I mentioned it to start at line 7, instead can we modify it so that it start from the line next to 
Port       Neighbor Device ID             Neighbor Port ID           TTL. 
Could we do that ?

Comment: It's all yours. Do whatever you wish to do. In fact I encourage you to play with code. This is the best way to learn.

Comment: Hi Saleem,

I am trying the same with another type of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open('tesxt.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if all(i not in line for i in ['Number', 'Last']) and line !='\n':
            print(line.strip().split()[:3])
```

it should work since you know `Number` and `Last` are not in the lines you need to print. There's no need to write a regex